# store data in asp.net pages (Not Sessions)

Tags: asp.net, maintainability, persistent-storage

I am creating 4 asp.net pages. first three pages have 'CONTINUE' button and last page has 'SUBMIT' button.  I am not allowed to use Sessions to store first three pages data. and i need to use 'BACK' button on last three pages. when i click 'BACK' button i need to maintain the previous page data entered by user.

As my pages do some postbacks, i cannot use javascript.history function.

My restrictions are:

As the application is served from a web farm, a session object cannot be used. However, for the purpose of this excersise, consider session object as database-like persistent space where you can store your data. your code should show an easy way to switch to a different persistent space.

What is databse like persistent space and how to write a code to switch to different persistent space?...

Please give me some idea on how to proceed....

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

`ASP.Net Wizard` Control can be an option in your case. because all `Next` and `Previous` navigation are managed by the control itself and there are Events Defined For each `Next` `Previous` and `Finish` Buttons. The controls State will automatically be stored in `Viewstate` and Managed by the Wizard control itself you don't need to repopulate the controls again and again.

You can find more detail here on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs0za4w6.aspx) article or see an [Example](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020103244/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/061406-1.aspx) Here

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. . If i use Wizard, then i will have no code to do. . this is my class assignment and i need to find a way to use code. . wat is meant by switching to different persistent space.  ?..

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest two solutions.
The first one uses database persistent storage for the session, since this solves the web farm anti-requirement. It is easy to do that and requires zero code, only configuration (and of course the database). The only (trivial in 99% of cases) caveat is that anything you store in session must be [Serializable].
This renders the web farm issue irrelevant, as all nodes will share the same database, which makes the problem moot. Check here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx

The second one is quite custom, using a number of hidden fields or other controls to store the information (essentially using the Viewstate to transport data) and cross-post between the pages (

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered storing data in database via some web service calls or something? Why not just make an Ajax call to store and retrieve data every time you navigate to the new page?

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "/Services/SomeServiceService.asmx/GetData",
              data: "{ 'myval' : 'someval'}",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              dataType: "json",
              error: function (resp) { alert("ERROR\n" + resp.responseText); },
              success: function (data) {
             }
    });
    $(".next").click(function(event){
      $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "/Services/SomeServiceService.asmx/SaveData",
               data: "{ 'myval' : 'someval'}",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               dataType: "json",
               error: function (resp) { alert("ERROR\n" + resp.responseText); },
               success: function (data) {
              }
     });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written a Navigation project for Web Forms you'll find interesting because it takes a new approach to remembering the pages visited and data entered, http://navigation.codeplex.com/

I've also written an introductory article about it in last month's MSDN Magazine, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/hh975349.aspx

If you're interested or need any help, let me know